# Foreign key with multiple models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, foreign-keys

I am creating ecommerce website. There are multiple categories. For example, phones, computers and others. I created a model for each of them. In OrderItems I want to foreign key each of them. So, I want to use multiple models in ForeignKey.

```
    models.py
class Telefon(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=300, choices=TELEFON, default="xiaomi")

    price = models.FloatField()
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url

class TV(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=300, choices=TELEFON, default="xiaomi")

    price = models.FloatField()
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url

Product={'Telefon', 'TV'}
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        total = self.product.price * self.quantity
        return total
```

So, how can I use multiple models in Foreign Key field in my OrderItems model.

Comment: Take a look at https://realpython.com/modeling-polymorphism-django-python/. Excellent read on implementing polymorphic relations in django

Comment: You're looking for many to many,